# Jenkins job dsl for bitbucket branch source plugin documentation with complete examples?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I currently have this:

```
multibranchPipelineJob("myjob") {
  branchSources {
    branchSource {
      source {
        bitbucket {
          credentialsId('bitbucket-login-user-pass')
          repoOwner('myteam')
          repository('myrepo')
          autoRegisterHook(true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I also need to add the following settings:
[image]

How do I add these settings in the config? Are they "traits" where do I go to see what traits I have available?

Comment: The best I've found was in the comments of this ticket: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39977

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is what I use (bitbucket wrapped with `organizationFolder`):

```
organizationFolder('example') {
    description('This contains branch source jobs for Bitbucket')
    displayName('The Organization Folder')
    triggers {
        periodic(86400)
    }
    organizations {
        bitbucket {
          repoOwner('myorg')
          credentialsId('BITBUCKET_CRED')
          autoRegisterHooks(false)
          traits {
            sourceRegexFilter {
              // A Java regular expression to restrict the project names.
              regex('.*')
            }
          }
        }
    }
    properties {
        mavenConfigFolderOverrideProperty {
            override(true)
            settings {
                settingsConfigId('DEFAULT_MAVEN_SETTINGS')
            }
        }
    }
    // discover Branches (workaround due to JENKINS-46202)
    configure { node ->
        // node represents <jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder>        
        def traits = node / 'navigators' / 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator' / 'traits'
        traits << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BranchDiscoveryTrait' {
            strategyId(3) // detect all branches
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can have a look at the jobDSL-API-Viewer of your jenkins-instance. This will show you all available jodDSL functions for your instance (jobDSL for installed plugins):

https://your.jenkins.url/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html

Comment: This is actually the best solution. Is this URL documented anywhere in the JOB DSL documentation?

Answer (score 2):

```
  multibranchPipelineJob('example'){
    branchSources{
      branchSource{
        source{
          bitbucket{
            repoOwner(project)
            repository(name)
            credentialsId('git_user')
            traits {
              bitbucketBranchDiscovery{
                strategyId(1)
              }
            }            
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Where traits are defined in the [DSL documentation](https://aesvl01.ddns.nl-htc01.nxp.com/jenkins/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.multibranchPipelineJob) and the strategyId correct value I found in the [bitbucket plugin source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/bitbucket/BranchDiscoveryTrait.java#L190).

Must be easy to discover the rest of the options from here.

Answer (score 0):

I think @prumand provide the best way to investigate the job dsl, below I'm adding example single repo multibranch pipeline from my side:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('/myjob') {

        factory {
            workflowBranchProjectFactory {
                scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
            }
        }

        branchSources {
          branchSource {
            source {
              bitbucket {
               id('123456789')
               serverUrl('https://bitbucket.org')
               credentialsId('bitbucket-access-id')
               repoOwner('myGroupOrUser')
               repository('myRepository')
               autoRegisterHook(true) // or not

                traits {
                  bitbucketBranchDiscovery {
                    strategyId(3) // 1 - exclude branches that are also filled as PRs, 3 - all branches
                  }
                  bitbucketPullRequestDiscovery {
                    strategyId(1) // 1 - merging PR with the current target branch revision, 2 - current pull request revision
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        orphanedItemStrategy {
          discardOldItems {
            numToKeep(3)
          }
        }

        triggers {
          periodicFolderTrigger {
            interval('86400000') // 1 day
          }
        }

      }
```