# How to trigger Jenkins build on merge to master branch from bitbucket, using bitbucket webhook?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

On merged PR to master branch I should run integration tests.
I know there is a lot of questions related to this topic when you are building Jenkins job from UI,
**but in my case I need a pipeline code (groovy).**

I can configure BitBucket webhook for jenkins, but then how to use it in script? I am not sure about that.

Comment: Since your issue is that you need DSL, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51555435/3730626)

Comment: @MB it leeds to non existing page 

Comment: The URL in the answer isn't a real URL. You're supposed to replace `your.jenkins.url` with your Jenkins instance's URL.